# Why is vue giving error "Cannot read properties of undefined" when array is initialiased even while displaying output?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have 2 vue files, App.vue and a component UsersPage.vue.

UsersPage.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
    data:() =>({
        usersList : []
    }),
    methods:{
        async createUsersList(){
            this.usersList = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((response)=> response.json());
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.createUsersList();
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <ul>
    <li v-for="user in usersList" :key="user.id"><b>Name:</b>{{user.name}}, <b>UserName:</b> {{user.username}},<b>ZipCode:</b> {{user.address.street}} </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

and App.vue:

```
<script>
import UsersPage from "./components/UsersPage.vue"

export default {
  components: {
    UsersPage,
  },
  data: () => ({
    currentPage: "Home",
  }),
  methods: {
    showHomePage() {
      this.currentPage = "Home";
    },
    showLoginPage() {
      this.currentPage = "Login";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <header class="header">
    <span class="logo">
      <img src="@/assets/vue-heart.png" width="30" />C'est La Vue
    </span>
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="showHomePage">Home</a>
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="showLoginPage">Login</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <UsersPage/>
</template>
```

When I run this, there is no error and the output still gets displayed. However, when I change the usersList to any array with any number of element(for example `usersList:[1,2]`), data is still displayed in correct format but following error is seen in the console of browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'street')
    at UsersPage.vue:19:149
    at renderList (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2894:22)
    at Proxy._sfc_render (UsersPage.vue:19:163)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:902:44)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5615:57)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:187:25)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5729:56)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5743:9)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5525:9)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5483:17)
```

Why is this error happening even though data is rendered properly and address also exists in https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?

Comment: i'd say it has something to do with `this.createUsersList();` being asynchronous

Comment: @Kakiz I thought so too but why is the page being rendered perfectly and the error is only seen in the browser's console?

Comment: The reason why you were still seeing the template after changing `usersList` to something invalid is because: when Vue updates the template, if it encounters an error it doesn't perform the change. So you were seeing the *"last valid template"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `v-for` you're using `users.address.street`.

When you pass `[1, 2]` to `usersList` and Vue parses those items through the `v-for`, it attempts to read the `adress.street` of each of those numbers.

Because they're numbers, their `address` is `undefined`. And when you try to access any property of `undefined`, you'll get the error you're getting.

**Note**: if you want your `v-for` to be able to parse items without an `address` without throwing an error, you could replace `users.address.street` with `users.address?.street`.
Documentation: [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing).

---

As a side note, you shouldn't call your iterator `users` as it might confuse you or other developers needing to modify that code as to what `users` is. You should probably call it `user` (e.g: `v-for="user in usersList" :key="user.id"`).
But that doesn't change the fact you can't access it's `address.street` property when it's a number.

Comment: Changed the question and wrote user. But why is the output still being rendered correctly when it tries to read the address part of number? Is it because I am using Vite and it autoupdates whenever the usersList gets changed?

Comment: @TheQuestioner, I just answered that question in a comment under your question. If you want, I can include it in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see it while typing the question in the comment, sorry. I got your answer now, no need to include comment in answer thanks.